# 'ORA-00913: too many values' while reading data from xml to user-defined record (PL/SQL)

Tags: oracle, plsql, xml-parsing

I get this error while executing the follwing PL/SQL code and I can't figure out why.

PLS-00382: expression is of wrong type
PL/SQL: ORA-00913: too many values
PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored

I understand that the cause of ORA-00913 is a mismatch of values in the two sets of data being referred to in the SELECT statement.

The code was working fine before I added the checkVar variable in the record. Just wanted to know if there is any way to fix this without taking out the checkVar from testRec record?

```
 DECLARE

  X XMLType:=XMLType( '<Testmain>
  <TeamSel>
    <code>abc123</code>
    <name>awrqer</name>
  </TeamSel>
   <TeamSel>
    <code>abc678</code>
    <name>gokhg</name>
  </TeamSel>
 </Testmain>

');


 TYPE testRec IS RECORD(
    name VARCHAR2(512),
    code  VARCHAR2(512),
    checkVar BOOLEAN:=FALSE
  );


  TYPE testRecTab IS TABLE OF testRec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  testList             testRecTab;


BEGIN

   SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list),'//Name') AS lname,
          EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list),'//Code') AS lcode
   BULK COLLECT
   INTO testList
   FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(X,'Testmain/TeamSel'))) xml_list; 

--rest of the code

END;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't select into a Boolean variable so I think there are two options:

a) Remove the boolean from your record type

b) Populate your table in a loop like the example below

```
DECLARE
  X XMLType:=XMLType( '<Testmain>
  <TeamSel>
    <code>abc123</code>
    <name>awrqer</name>
  </TeamSel>
   <TeamSel>
    <code>abc678</code>
    <name>gokhg</name>
  </TeamSel>
 </Testmain>

');

 TYPE testRec IS RECORD(
    name VARCHAR2(512),
    code  VARCHAR2(512),
    checkVar BOOLEAN:=FALSE
  );

  TYPE testRecTab IS TABLE OF testRec INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

  lTestRec             testRec;
  testList             testRecTab;

BEGIN   
   FOR cRecord IN (
     SELECT EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list),'//name') lname,
            EXTRACTVALUE(VALUE(xml_list),'//code') lcode
     FROM TABLE(XMLSEQUENCE(EXTRACT(X,'Testmain/TeamSel'))) xml_list
   )
   LOOP
     lTestRec.name := cRecord.lname;
     lTestRec.code := cRecord.lcode;

     testList(testList.count + 1) := lTestRec;
   END LOOP;

--rest of the code

END;
```